# display shortcodes outside of the_content

Tags: shortcode

Is there a way to display shortcode content outside of the_content?

I am building a custom theme who's theme options includes two text boxes that can be displayed on the front page.  I want to be able to display shortcode content placed in these text box options.  The theme uses files from the Options Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) for use shortcodes outside fomr default content. You can also parse this in your function, there get the output of your textfields, like the follow example for a custom field:

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cfield', TRUE ) )
    echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cfield', $single = TRUE ) );
```

Comment: Thanks @bueltge.  The shortcode is not part of a post.  It is part of the theme options.

Comment: The function works in all fields, also in your theme options.

Comment: @Steve, `do_shortcode( get_option(etc...`