# Get shortcode from the content and display it in other place (in sidebar, for example)

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode: [content_block]

If that shortcode exists in content and has the attribute position=top, I would like to remove it from the content and display it in other place. For example, in sidebar.

In summary:

- Detect if [content_block] exists
- If exists, detect if has the attibute position=top
- If has the attribute, then store the complete shortcode to display it in a different place (for example in the sidebar).
- And remove it from the content.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can look to the code WordPress uses for parsing Shortcodes to get some ideas about how to do this. There are a couple of helpful core functions to simplify things.

```
// our callback function to check for the shortcode.
// this is where you'd put code to set a flag for rendering the shortcode elsewhere
// the complete tag is in $tag[0], which can be passed to do_shortcode later
function wpd_check_shortcode( $tag ){
    if( 'content_block' == $tag[2] ){
        // convert string of attributes to array of key=>val pairs
        $attributes = shortcode_parse_atts( $tag[3] );
        if( array_key_exists( 'position', $attributes )
            && 'top' == $attributes['position'] ){
                // move shortcode to sidebar here
                // return empty to strip shortcode
                return '';
        }
    }
    // return any non-matching shortcodes
    return $tag[0];
}

// source text with shortcode
$text = 'lorem ipsum [content_block]';

// this generates a regex pattern for all registered shortcodes
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

// process all shortcodes through our callback function
$text = preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'wpd_check_shortcode', $text );

// modified $text with shortcode removed
echo $text;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But how can I display the shortcode in the sidebar?

Comment: [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) @user1443216

Comment: put the shortcode in a var, it will be in `$tag[0]`, or better, wrap the whole thing in a class and set a class var, then output that when in your sidebar by passing it to do_shortcode.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to display it using $tag[0] in my sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse168789_shortcode_checker' );
function wpse168789_shortcode_checker( $content ) {
    // 1. Does the shortcode exist?
    if( has_shortcode( $content, 'content_block' ) ) {
        // 2. Is it using position='top'?
        $regex = '/\[content_block[^\]]*position=[\'"]?top[\'"]?[^\]]*\]/';
        if( preg_match( $regex, $content ) ) {
                // 3. Filter the shortcode out of the_content
                $content = preg_replace( $regex, '', $content );
            }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

You will probably have to massage the regular expression `$regex` -- I haven't tested this.

As for displaying the shortcode's content in another location -- [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80381/display-shortcodes-outside-of-the-content) might guide you.

### References

- [`has_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode)
- [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match)
- [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the regular expression fails. The error is: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

Comment: Whoops. I think that should now be fixed.

Comment: Ok. There is no errors now. But if I have [content_block position="top" colour="blue" size="medium"] your function remove the shortcode from the content. That is correct, but now I would like to save that shortcode to display it for example in the sidebar. How can I do it?